# Kolla AIO deploy fail: Hostname has to resolve IP address while starting rabbitMQ container?

Tags: deployment, rabbitmq, openstack

I'm trying to deploy Kolla in AIO. 
I build images using the command:

```
kolla-build -p default -b ubuntu -t binary
```

I am deploying it in my local system.
I'm using ubuntu 16.04, built images. I'm not using a local registry. 
`kolla-ansible precheck` runs fine 
 
`kolla-ansible deploy` gives me an error while starting rabbitmq
My host name is DESKTOP
 
The output of hosts file
 `cat /etc/hosts` 
    127.0.0.1   localhost
    127.0.1.1   DESKTOP

```
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback <br>
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

The error is as follows

```
    TASK: [rabbitmq | fail msg="Hostname has to resolve to IP address of api_interface"] *** 
    failed: [localhost] => (item={u'cmd': [u'getent', u'ahostsv4', u'DESKTOP'], u'end': u'2017-02-26 00:45:10.399323', u'stderr': u'', u'stdout': u'127.0.1.1       STREAM DESKTOP\n127.0.1.1       DGRAM  \n127.0.1.1       RAW    ', u'changed': False, u'rc': 0, 'item': 'localhost', u'warnings': [], u'delta': u'0:00:00.001585', 'invocation': {'module_name': u'command', 'module_complex_args': {}, 'module_args': u'getent ahostsv4 DESKTOP'}, 'stdout_lines': [u'127.0.1.1       STREAM DESKTOP', u'127.0.1.1       DGRAM  ', u'127.0.1.1       RAW    '], u'start': u'2017-02-26 00:45:10.397738'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"changed": false, "cmd": ["getent", "ahostsv4", "DESKTOP"], "delta": "0:00:00.001585", "end": "2017-02-26 00:45:10.399323", "invocation": {"module_args": "getent ahostsv4 DESKTOP", "module_complex_args": {}, "module_name": "command"}, "item": "localhost", "rc": 0, "start": "2017-02-26 00:45:10.397738", "stderr": "", "stdout": "127.0.1.1       STREAM DESKTOP\n127.0.1.1       DGRAM  \n127.0.1.1       RAW    ", "stdout_lines": ["127.0.1.1       STREAM DESKTOP", "127.0.1.1       DGRAM  ", "127.0.1.1       RAW    "], "warnings": []}}
    msg: Hostname has to resolve to IP address of api_interface

    FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

    PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
               to retry, use: --limit @/home/ravichandran/site.retry

localhost                  : ok=84   changed=11   unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Please help. Also let me know if additional information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your hosts file has a mapping of DESKTOP to 127.0.0.1. Your formatting is a little off but this appears to be what's missing.